# Is there evidence to suggest that the different and contrasting behaviours we collectively call 'sensitive' have a common root cause?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, metacognition, behavior

There appear to be [two different meanings of the word 'sensitive'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251531/does-describing-someone-as-sensitive-conflate-two-different-ideas) when describing people's behaviour:

1. that the person being described lacks the emotional resilience to cope with an everyday situation.
2. one who is very observant of people's behaviour, and able to display empathy in a way that connects with people. One who treats people with care, with great sensitivity to their situation.

Now I wonder if the English language is giving us some insights here. It seems reasonable that people in the first bucket have less maturity than the second. But they share a common ability to sense the subtleties of the situation. It is almost as if they are the same thing on a spectrum of maturity.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that the different and contrasting behaviours we collectively call 'sensitive' have a common root cause?**